# This pointer - C++ linked list

Tags: pointers, struct, linked-list, this

I was trying to create a linked list with structs. The idea is to use 2 different stucts, one which is a node, and another which is a pointer to the nodes (so, I can link the nodes together).

But I wanted to initialize the pointer to the first node as NULL, and create subsequent nodes later:

I am having an error in the 2 constructor methods (List and Polynomial), I can't use the operator = like the way I am. But I can't understand why.

```
struct List
{
    //Data members to hold an array of pointers, pointing to a specific node
    Node *list[100];

    //Default constructor
    List();
};

List::List()
{
    *list[0] = NULL;
}

class Polynomial
{
    public:
    [...]

    private:
        List *poly;                         //Store the pointer links in an array
        Node first_node;
        int val;
};

Polynomial::Polynomial()
{
    poly = new List();
}

/*******************************************************************************************************************************/
// Method   : initialize()
// Description  : This function creates the linked nodes
/*******************************************************************************************************************************/
Polynomial::void initialize(ifstream &file)
{
    int y[20];
    double x[20];
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    //Read from the file
    file >> x[j];
    file >> y[j];

    first_node(x[j], y[j++]);                       //Create the first node with coef, and pwr
    *poly->list[i] = &first_node;                       //Link to the fist node

    //Creat a linked list
    while(y[j] != 0)
    {
        file >> x[j];
        file >> y[j];
        *poly->list[++i] = new Node(x[j], y[j++]);
    }

    val = i+1;                              //Keeps track of the number of nodes
}
```

I have been getting errors in the Polynomial constructor and the List constructor.

Comment: Why don't you use a `std::vector<Node>` instead?

Comment: That doesn't look like a linked list.

Comment: error: in the List::List() constructor, there is no match for 'operator ='...the same error exists for the polynomial constructor. And I want to implement my own nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems not like the link list. Maybe you need a struct `node` (right ?) contain information and `List` contain many `node` after ? If this two, I has two solutions:

first. very (and very) common.

```
typedef struct nNode{
  int info;
  string name;
  //and any information you want this node has.
  struct nNode *pNext;
} Node;
```

Second. Style like I see in your code.

```
typedef struct nNode{
  int info;
  string name;
  //and any information you want this node has
}Node;
typedef struct nList{
  Node node;
  struct nList *pNext;
} List;
```

You see, the second version looks like the first :)

Comment: But, what is it that I am doing wrong in my code? I have a struct Node which creates a Node. And a struct List, which holds the pointers to all the other nodes. Is there something wrong with that logic?

Comment: I have now included in the original code, the part where I try to link the nodes, please can you take a look at that.

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite clear from your code exactly what you want to do.

But, the code:

```
Node *list[100];
```

means an array of 100 Node pointers.

When you do:

```
*list[0] = NULL;
```

you are dereferencing the list[0] pointer, which isn't what you want.  list[0] will get you a Node *, and *list[0] will get you a Node.

Either you mean:

```
list[0] = NULL;
```

or you want to create an array of Node **.  I'm not sure from your code what it is you want.

Comment: I am trying to access each Node through the struct "list", and I want to change the data or link it together with another node.

Comment: I wanted to set the pointer to the first node to NULL, meaning, point to nothing...since there isn't to be pointed to.

Comment: Then what you want is "list[0] = NULL;"

Comment: Yes, I understood what I was doing wrong, thankyou! however, I am getting another error in the Polynomial constructor as well. What I am trying to do is create a list with a 100 nodes, however, I am getting an error when I do poly = new list()...